# Factorization of huge integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

I have to factorize the integer $n = 2^{214313833}-1$. Obviously this is not a prime, because $214313833 = 9623 \cdot 22271$, so $n_1=2^{9623}-1$, $n_2=2^{22271}-1$ are divisor of $n$, though $n\neq n_1 \cdot n_2$.

How can I get at least one prime factor of $n$? Are the smaller numbers still handleable by a normal computer (or am I too naive?)? Is there any other trick?

Comment: Why do you have to factor it? Morbid fascination? Is someone making you do this? What do you think the Q&A equivalent of *blink three times if you need help* is?

Comment: $2^{22271}-1$ is divisible by $44543$, which is prime.

Comment: Robert is alluding to the fact that all prime factors of $2^n-1$ are of the form $2nm + 1$ for some $m$.

Comment: @mixedmath: I don't know, I believe my drink was spiked... when I woke up, I found myself in a closed room with a steel door.  It has a combination lock, and there is a handwritten note besides that says "hint: prime factor of $2^{214313833}-1$". I'm going to try Robert Israel's answer.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus:  The fact you noted depends on the exponent $n$ being prime.

Comment: Curiously $9623$ is itself the smallest of three prime factors of $2^{283}-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ be one odd prime factor of $2^{22271}-1$

$$2^{22271}-1\equiv 0 \pmod{p}\implies 2^{22271}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

Since $22271$ is prime, the order of $2$ modulo $p$ is $22271$ and the order must divide $\phi(p)$ 
$$22271 \mid \phi(p)\\22271\mid (p-1)\\p = 22271k+1$$

$k$ has to be even for $p$ to be odd 
$$p = 44542l + 1$$

Now you may plugin different values for $l$ and check divisibility for those that produce primes.

Answer (score 2):

Factoring Mersenne primes is not easy to do. The Mersenne prime search is a huge collaborative effort using computer programs to factor Mersenne primes.

You have to factor $2^{9623}-1$ and $2^{22271}-1$.

For large exponents this can be really computing heavy. [You may be able to use some of these algorithms though](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_a_Mersenne_number)

Comment: While it will certainly help to factor the Mersenne candidates $2^{9623} - 1$ and $2^{22271} - 1$, that will not give all  factors of $2^{9623\cdot 22271} - 1$, and it might not even give the smallest prime factor.